# Removing square wave like artifacts from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a numpy array which is basically a data column from excel sheet. This data is acquired through low-pass 10 Hz filter DAS but due to some ambiguity it contains square wave like artifacts. The data now has to be filtered at 0.4 Hz Highpass Butterworth filter, which I do through scipy.signal. But after applying Highpass fiter, the square wave like artifacts change into spikes. When applying scipy.median to it I am not able to successfully filter the spikes. What should I try?

The following pic shows the original data. 
[image]

Following pic shows highpass filter of 0.4 Hz applied followed by median filter of order 3

[image]

Even a median filter of order 51 is not useful.

[image]

Comment: Thresholding might work. Just trash anything outside 3-sigma in the original data.

Comment: Fix your tags please

Comment: Sigma for data except Square region is around 1.6 but with square region it is  around 26. I am afraid thresholding value higher v 3 times  26  would not be any helpful.

Comment: 26x3 = 78. They looks good. Maybe reduce it to 2.5 or do it iteratively

Comment: Can you provide me with the data?

Comment: have you tried looking at the derivative of the signal?

Comment: @DrBwts This square wave like artifact is due to sensor not properly working. In most cases we get sinusoid only. Also I need to find only max and min of this variation after filtering.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of detecting the spikes by calculating the derivative & then replacing those regions with an interpolated sequence

Comment: If you provide me with a link to the data in a text format, I can demo how to fix the artifacts.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Here is the Google drive Link to concerned data. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GBt9_WjtfclMfTOVtCLULh9BWiPZ_SgD

Answer (score 0):

If your input is always expected to have a significant outlier, I would recommend an iterative filtering approach.

Here is your data plotted along with the mean, 1-sigma, 2-sigma and 3-sigma lines:

[image: sigmas1]

I would start by removing everything above and below 2-sigma from the mean. Since that will tighten the distribution, I would recommend doing the iterations over and over until the size of the un-trimmed data remains the same. I would recommend increasing the threshold geometrically to avoid trimming "good" data. Finally, you can fill in the missing points with the mean of the remainder or something like that.

Here is a sample implementation, with no attempt at optimization whatsoever:

```
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', skiprows=1)
x = np.arange(data.size)
loop_data = data
prev_size = 0
nsigma = 2
while prev_size != loop_data.size:
    mean = loop_data.mean()
    std = loop_data.std()
    mask = (loop_data < mean + nsigma * std) & (loop_data > mean - nsigma * std)
    prev_size = loop_data.size
    loop_data = loop_data[mask]
    x = x[mask]
    # Constantly expanding sigma guarantees fast loop termination
    nsigma *= 2

# Reconstruct the mask
mask = np.zeros_like(data, dtype=np.bool)
mask[x] = True
# This destroys the original data somewhat
data[~mask] = data[mask].mean()
```

This approach may not be optimal in all situations, but I have found it to be fairly robust most of the time. There are lots of tweakable parameters. You may want to change your increase factor from 2, or even go with a linear instead of geometrical increase (although I tried the latter and it really didn't work well). You could also use IQR instead of sigma, since it is more robust against outliers.

Here is an image of the resulting dataset (with the removed portion in red and the original dotted):

[image]

Another artifact of interest: here are the plots of the data showing the trimming progression and how it affects the cutoff points. Plots show the data, with cut portions in red, and a the n-sigma line for the remainder. The title shows how much the sigma shrinks:

[image]
[image]
[image]